# How do I access members of thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, reference

I have this member of thread

```
public int a;
```

I am passing threads id to static function, where I want to do something like

```
function(long threadId, int a){
    synchronized (threadId){
            threadId.a = a;
            threadId.notify();
    }
}
```

I know, that threads id is just long and it wont work this way, so how can i reference thread with id i get in functions arguments?

Comment: Well *why* are you trying to use threads in that way anyway, rather than passing a `Thread` reference? It's also not really clear what you mean by "I have this member of thread" - nor why you're trying to synchronize on a primitive value...

Comment: To clarify, have you extended the `Thread` class in which you have added the field `a`? Or do you have some other class that has field `a`?

Comment: threadWithMemberA extends Thread

Comment: @Pan.student as Jon suggested the best practice is to pass to that static method the threadWithMemberA instance

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not synchronizing primitive value, thats just simplification for this question.

Comment: @Pan.student you do not need to synchronize it since the member a belongs to a Thread instance

Comment: So why have it at all? That's not "simplification" - that's just misleading. Your whole question is very vague and hard to understand at the moment.

Comment: @JonSkeet i agree `Pan.student` please rephrase your question

Comment: Any feedback on my answer @Pan.student?  Remind to upvote and/or accept it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> I know, that threads id is just long and it wont work this way, so how can i reference thread with id i get in functions arguments?

You really can't do what you want to do.  You could keep a map of thread-id to associated `Thread` or `Runnable` class yourself however and use it to lookup the id.

```
  Thread thread = new MyThread();
  thread.start();
  idMap.put(thread.getId(), thread);
```

The right way to do this is to define your own class and deal with the object instead of the thread-id.  It is recommended to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`.  Something like:

```
public class MyRunnable impelments Runnable {
    public int a;
    ...
    public void run() {
       // code run in the thread
       synchronized (this) {
          this.wait();
       }
       System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable();
Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start();
...
public void function(MyRunnable runnable, int a) {
   synchronized (runnable){
       runnable.a = a;
       runnable.notify();
   }
}
```

Better would be to have a setter on the `MyRunnable` which encapsulates the process:

```
public synchronized void setA(int a) {
   this.a = a;
   this.notify();
}
```

An alternative would be to have the thread can share with the notifying thread a `BlockingQueue` which saves you from the wait/notify.  The main thread (or whomever is calling `function`) then puts an entity into the queue and the thread pulls it out.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I solved it by passing reference of thread, instead of passing id.